# When/why use types from typing module for type hints

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

What is exactly the 'right' way for type hinting?
My IDE (and resulting code) works fine for type hints using either of below options, but some types can be imported from the typing module. Is there a preference for using the import from the typing module over builtins (like list or dict)?

Examples:

```
from typing import Dict
def func_1(arg_one: Dict) -> Dict:
    pass
```

and

```
def func_2(arg_one: dict) -> dict:
    pass
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "right" way is to use builtins when possible (e.g. `dict` over `typing.Dict`). `typing.Dict` is only needed if you use Python < 3.9. In older versions you couldn't use generic annotations like `dict[str, Any]` with builtins, you had to use `Dict[str, Any]`. See [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no big difference between `typing.Dict` and `dict`.

Just `typing.Dict` is actually a Generic Type, so it allows you to specify subtypes inside the brackets.

Like:

```
from typing import Dict
def func_1(arg_one: Dict[str, int]) -> Dict:
    pass
```

But `typing.Dict` is only necessary if your Python version is under 3.9. Other wise you could do the same with regular `dict`s.

Example Python >= 3.9:

```
def func_1(arg_one: dict[str, int]) -> dict:
    pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by " is actually a Generic Type"? To me, this suggests that `dict` is something else. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes they are different, `dict` is the actual built-in collection that is actually used as a dictionary. But `typing.Dict` is its associated "generic type" and is used for type hinting/checking. A generic type is nothing more than a type that can be parameterized. As stated above PEP 585 (https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) is a good read on this subject